# javascript - replace string with dynamically created element

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to replace a placeholder with a dynamically created element.

**Approach**

```
var myhtml = 'some html and stuff {IMAGE} some more html';
myhtml = myhtml.replace(/{IMAGE}/g, document.createElement('img'));
console.log(myhtml); // some html and stuff [object HTMLImageElement] some more html
```

How can I make it so it replaces it with the actual html output?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first append your dynamically created element to an empty container (possibly dynamically created DIV) and then get the innerHTML of that container.

Example:

```
var myhtml = 'some html and stuff {IMAGE} some more html';
var elem = document.createElement("img");
var elemContainer = document.createElement("div");
elemContainer.appendChild(elem);
var elemHtml = elemContainer.innerHTML;
myhtml = myhtml.replace(/{IMAGE}/g, elemHtml);
console.log(myhtml);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an ugly code like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript>
  var tmp =  document.createElement("img");
  var tmp2 = document.createElement("div");
  tmp2.appendChild(tmp);
  alert(tmp2.innerHTML);
</script>
```

Comment: sorry this is not what I was asking for. I know I can append it but I need to put it somewhere specific.